# Counting audio channels with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file

Does ffmpeg have a way to look at an audio file and report whether it's mono or stereo?  I need a way to count the number of channels and assign that number to a variable in a Windows batch file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ffprobe -show_entries stream=channels -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0 audio.wav
```

Comment: I get error: `'ffprobe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Zimba You need to install `ffprobe` and/or put it in your `PATH`.

Comment: I see, extra download

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg.exe -i %a% 2>&1 | find "Audio"
```

shows the bitrate, codec and whether audio is mono or stereo, with stream numbers.

No need to count number of tracks in audio stream; just select the stream & ffmpeg will show number of channels/tracks eg. mono, stereo or 5.1 etc. No need for extra downloads eg. ffprobe.

To save selected audio channel type to a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %i in ('ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i %a% 2^>^&1 ^| find "Stream #0:1"') do set channel=%i
```

ffmpeg also allows [mixing of channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation).

Comment: The output from `ffmpeg` is not meant to be used in scripting: it can be "fragile" and requires extra parsing tools. That's what `ffprobe` is for.

Comment: Robust scripts can be built with ffmpeg to do the job, without extra downloads like ffprobe.

Comment: I found this approach useful although the "2>&1" part generates an error, at least on Windows. But the output still reports the streams found in the input, and whether they are Video or Audio. In fact, it works just as well with nothing but the -i filename argument.

Note that the output also includes the name of the file, so if that might contain the literal text 'Audio' you need to be more discriminating in your 'find'. I used a regex, "Stream #.*Audio"